# OpenCV with CMake not working, unsure why

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Trying to get OpenCV included in my C++ project, but having issues for some reason...

I followed the instructions to install from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ../opencv
make -j4
make install
```

I can see it in my /usr/local/include under 'opencv4'

In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
add_executable(Nssams main.cpp ${BACKWARD_ENABLE})

add_subdirectory(camera)
add_subdirectory(mqtt_client)
add_subdirectory(jsoncpp)
add_subdirectory(serial)
add_subdirectory(backward-cpp)

if(${BUILD_WITH_TESTING})
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")

target_link_libraries(Nssams
    mqtt
    camera
    jsoncpp
    serial
    PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3-static
    spdlog
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

The messages are spitting out:

```
[cmake] -- OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include/opencv4
[cmake] -- OpenCV LIBS = opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;
```

But when I try to #include, i.e.

```
#include "opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp"
```

It's red underlined and the error says

```
#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/bwhitely/Projects/NSSAMS/nssams-cpp-ebcmos/src/camera/ebcmos.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "opencv2/core/cvdef.h" (dependency of "opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp")C/C++(1696)
```

Where am I going wrong?
I have done very similar things with the spdlog library that's in the CMakeLists.txt with no issues. Just built it from source, added it to the CMakeLists.txt and could use without issues

EDIT:
CMakeLists.txt build output while having #include "opencv4/opencv2/core/core.hpp" included in a .cpp file

```
[main] Building folder: nssams-cpp-ebcmos 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/bwhitely/Projects/NSSAMS/nssams-cpp-ebcmos/build --config Debug --target all -j 4 --
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target backward_object
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target camera
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jsoncpp
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mqtt
[build] [  6%] Built target backward_object
[build] [ 12%] Building CXX object src/camera/CMakeFiles/camera.dir/ebcmos.cpp.o
[build] [ 31%] Built target mqtt
[build] [ 43%] Built target jsoncpp
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target serial
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target backward
[build] [ 56%] Built target backward
[build] [ 68%] Built target serial
[build] In file included from /home/bwhitely/Projects/NSSAMS/nssams-cpp-ebcmos/src/camera/ebcmos.cpp:8:
[build] /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
[build]    48 | #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] gmake[2]: *** [src/camera/CMakeFiles/camera.dir/build.make:104: src/camera/CMakeFiles/camera.dir/ebcmos.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:219: src/camera/CMakeFiles/camera.dir/all] Error 2
[build] gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/bwhitely/Projects/NSSAMS/nssams-cpp-ebcmos/build --config Debug --target all -j 4 -- exited with code: 2 and signal: null
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

It does build correctly if I do not have that include defined
output below:

```
[main] Building folder: nssams-cpp-ebcmos 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/bwhitely/Projects/NSSAMS/nssams-cpp-ebcmos/build --config Debug --target all -j 4 --
[build] [  6%] Building CXX object src/camera/CMakeFiles/camera.dir/ebcmos.cpp.o
[build] [ 12%] Built target backward_object
[build] [ 25%] Built target jsoncpp
[build] [ 43%] Built target mqtt
[build] [ 56%] Built target serial
[build] [ 68%] Built target backward
[build] [ 75%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libcamera.a
[build] [ 87%] Built target camera
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target Nssams
[build] [ 93%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/Nssams
[build] [100%] Built target Nssams
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: "It's red underlined and the error says" - This error doesn't look like the one emitted when you **build** the project. It looks like the one which just prevents **IDE** to correctly **navigate** between e.g. functions in your sources. So, whether your project can be built? If not, then show (add to the question post) the exact error caused by building it. If you want to solve IDE problems, then we need to know at least which IDE you are using.

Comment: I have updated the OP with the output of building when having an opencv include in one of my source files. If I remove the include, it looks to build fine. My IDE is VSCode

Comment: The error message is about building the `camera` target (Note on the `camera.dir` component in the compiled object path: `src/camera/CMakeFiles/camera.dir/ebcmos.cpp.o`). But only `Nssams` target is linked with OpenCV (by `target_link_libraries` call).

Comment: Ahhh yes. That looks like the problem. I moved most of the OpenCV CMake calls (find_package(), target_link_libraries() and include_directories() into the CMakeLists.txt that's within the camera directory, and that looks to have fixed it. It was previously in the CMakeLists.txt in the parent directory (same dir as main.cpp). I should read the error output more closely as I should have picked that up. Taking over the project and CMake is not one of my strong suits. Appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: `"opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp"` -- that `opencv4` bit shouldn't really be there (The include path for opencv is `/usr/local/include/opencv4` as shown) It only works since `/usr/local/include` is also in the include path.